# Tkinter window in python doesn't open?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

So I was making a Personal Assistant type program in python, but in the middle of debugging it stopped opening the GUI window. I have a root.mainloop and no errors show in the shell. Any suggestions? This is one of my first Tkinter projects so there might be some really obvious things that I missed :)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import os
import subprocess
from random import *
needed = True
path = ''
items = ["CODE", "INTERNET", "FILES", "TIME", "TERMINAL", "MEDIA"]

root = Tk()
root.title = "PPA"


def Greet():
    #Generate a greeting
    greeting = choice(["Welcome back", "Hello", "Good to see you"])
    #Greet the user
    PPA.set(greeting,"Master")
    time.sleep(0.7)

def Main(need, user):
    global needed
    while needed == True:
        #Ask user what they need
        PPA.set("What would you like to do?")
        if need == "CODE":
            PPA.set("Ok, I will open up the code editor")
            path = "geany"
            subprocess.call(path)
        elif need == "INTERNET":
            PPA.set("Ok, I will open the internet browser")
            path = "chromium-browser"
            subprocess.call(path)
        elif need == "TIME":
            PPA.set("This is the time:")
            PPA.set(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        elif need == "FILES":
            PPA.set("Ok, I will open the file browser")
            path = "pcmanfm"
            subprocess.call(path)
        elif need == "TERMINAL":
            PPA.set("Ok, I will open the terminsl")
            path = "lxterminal"
            subprocess.call(path)
        elif need == "MEDIA":
            PPA.set("Ok, I will open the media player")
            path = "vlc"
            subprocess.call(path)
        else:
            pass
        PPA.set("Can I still be of assistance?")
        user.set(need)
        if user == "NO":
            needed = False
        else:
            need = ""
            pass

def Farewell():
    farewell = choice(["Farewell", "Goodbye", "See you soon"])
    PPA.set(farewell,"Master")
    

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

need = StringVar()
need_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=need)
need_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
user = StringVar()
PPA = StringVar()
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=PPA).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Enter", command=Main(need, user).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey! Do you mean "no errors in the shell" or are there errors?

Comment: There no errors whatsoever right now

Comment: what have you done to debug this? It doesn't look like it's possible for the code to ever break out of this loop: `while need not in items:`. If `need` is not in `items`, there's no way that loop will ever end.

Comment: I'm sure if this is the best way, but I just went and fixed errors as they they appeared. Ill see if I can do something about the loop

Comment: Do you think it would work if I deleted what you pointed out?

Comment: I got rid of the ```need not in items``` that wasn't needed, but still no gui.